# Spring MVC: What is an HttpEntity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have read the spring docs about the HttpEntity. Accordingly, it represents a Http response/request entity. I arrived in the conclusion that this is the same as a character in a character stream. However, it consists of a header and a body.

Please elaborate about HttpEntity or Http response/request in general. Links are welcome.

Comment: I see my error now. Thank you for marking it duplicate

Answer (score 2):

The **Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC)** framework is designed around a DispatcherServlet that dispatches requests to handlers, with configurable handler mappings, view resolution, locale, time zone and theme resolution as well as support for uploading files. The default handler is based on the @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations, offering a wide range of flexible handling methods. With the introduction of Spring 3.0, the @Controller mechanism also allows you to create RESTful Web sites and applications, through the @PathVariable annotation and other features.

The **HttpEntity** is similar to **@RequestBody** and **@ResponseBody**. Besides getting access to the request and response body, HttpEntity (and the response-specific subclass ResponseEntity) also allows access to the request and response headers.

Source : [Spring Web MVC framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)